# "Unsupported action" error on attempting to install an extension

Tags: extension, error, installation

I'm trying to install the extension [Extended Mailing Stats](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-mailing-stats) on Civi 4.6.14 running on Wordpress 4.4.2.

I added the extension's files to my Civi extension directory, went to the Civi extension manager and clicked Install. I got this error (from the log file):

```
Apr 07 04:34:06  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => Unsupported action
    [code] => 
)


Apr 07 04:34:06  [info] $backTrace = #0 path/to/install/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(364): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 path/to/install/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php(80): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Unsupported action")
#2 path/to/install/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(455): CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions->preProcess()
#3 path/to/install/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(94): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#4 path/to/install/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), "display")
#5 path/to/install/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), "display")
#6 path/to/install/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(363): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
#7 path/to/install/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(395): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#8 path/to/install/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(174): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->edit(1, NULL)
#9 path/to/install/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php(125): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->run()
#10 path/to/install/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions->run((Array:3), NULL)
#11 path/to/install/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#12 path/to/install/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#13 path/to/install/civicrm.php(1199): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#14 [internal function](): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#15 path/to/install/wp-includes/plugin.php(525): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:1))
#16 path/to/install/wp-admin/admin.php(236): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#17 {main}
```

It seems the action is "display". Not sure if it's supposed to be that. On the Civi backend, when I get the error, in the URL itself it says "action=add".

Any idea why this is happening?
Thanks.